# Python - Face Api by microsoft - there is no persisted faces of person

Tags: python, face-api

I have  trained the face API using `person_group.train()` method.
Then I have used `person_group.status()` to get the status of training but it showed:

> {'status': 'failed', 'createdDateTime': '6/19/2018 10:34:40 AM',
>   'lastActionDateTime': '06/19/2018 10:34:40', 'message': 'There is no
>   persisted faces of person in group 22'}

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you add `person` in your `personGroup`, and added `faces` to those `persons`?

Comment: yeah i figured it out . Thanks for the help :)